# How to remove unwanted namespace in Flutter iOS app name displayed in Info.plist?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, namespaces, info.plist

How can we remove 2 namespace from flutter app name in iOS

I have been facing issue in name displaying in flutter app for iOS side

i.e. In **Info.plist** file where we add name in CFBundleDisplayName.
There '**FSP**' gets added by itself between 2 words and when we try to remove that and add single space in between that again gets change it to FSP.

In recent app tray sometimes it looks perfect but most of the times the name contains 2 space in both app tray, settings and in app list of iOS.

[Click here for image reference attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpryf.png)

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>ABCD XYZ</string>
```

Is there any solution for this. Thanks for your help in advance